# VBA that adds or removes "budget" series from all charts in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new at this, but I am trying to make a toggle switch that will add or remove the "budget" series from all the charts in MyArray. The sub itself works fine, but the private subs it calls on seem to have no effect. One thing to consider is that the "budget series" isn't always just called "budget" e.g. "budget gross profit"etc. any help would be awesome. thanks guys

```
`Sub ToggleBudget()

If Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Button 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Add Budget" Then
    Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Button 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Remove Budget"
    Call Budget_On
ElseIf Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Button 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Remove Budget" Then
    Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Button 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Add Budget"
    Call Budget_Off
End If
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub


Private Sub Budget_On()

Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Array("Company KPI", "People KPI", "Sales & Mkg KPI", "Service & Operations KPI", "Seasonality & Industry Comp")
        For Each ChartObject In MyArray
                For Each SeriesCollection In Charts
                    For Each Series In SeriesCollection
                        If Series.Name Like "*Budget*" Then
                        Chart.SeriesCollection(Series.Name).IsFiltered = True
                        End If
                    Next Series
               Next SeriesCollection
    Next ChartObject

End Sub


Private Sub Budget_Off()

Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Array("Company KPI", "People KPI", "Sales & Mkg KPI", "Service & Operations KPI", "Seasonality & Industry Comp")
        For Each ChartObject In MyArray
                For Each SeriesCollection In Charts
                    For Each Series In SeriesCollection
                        If Series.Name Like "*Budget*" Then
                        Chart.SeriesCollection(Series.Name).IsFiltered = False
                        End If
                    Next Series
               Next SeriesCollection
    Next ChartObject

End Sub`
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to ensure that each budget on/off do what is requested?  There should be an error if soemthing is awry, but if nothing is happening, then possibly you are not able to find A) a series or B) a series with a name like *budget*

Comment: I believe your issue is the for each chartobject in myarray.  You are looping through names and not particularly the charts themselves.  If you were to use **For Each chartobject In Sheets("NAME").ChartObjects** then compare the name of the chart to yoru array, then you might get somewhere.

Comment: i tried that, i think the issue lies in that it isn't finding a seriescollection or series. ive played arround with it and am not having any luck, any other suggestions?

Comment: Could be misreading this, but you don't seem to actually be referencing the chartObject thats being iterated through from the array. `For Each ChartObject In MyArray.... For Each SeriesCollection In Charts`. Shouldn't this be something like `For Each ChartObject In MyArray...For Each SeriesCollection In ChartObject`

Comment: originally it was ringing that as an error. now it is working but doesn't seem to like the name part of    {If Series.Name Like "*Budget*" Then  }